# Looking for a string with regex and delete the whole line

Tags: regex, textpad

I am trying to find in Textpad a character with regex (for example "#") and if it is found the whole line should be deleted. The # is not at the beginnen of the line nor at the end but somewehre in between and not connected to another word, number or charakter - it stands alone with a whitespace left and right, but of course the rest of the line contains words and numbers.

Example:

```
My first line
My second line with # hash
My third line# with hash
```

Result:

```
My first line
My third line# with hash
```

How could I accomplish that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's break it down:

```
^     # Start of line
.*    # any number of characters (except newline)
[ \t] # whitespace (tab or space)
\#    # hashmark
[ \t] # whitespace (tab or space)
.*    # any number of characters (except newline)
```

or, in a single line: `^.*[ \t]#[ \t].*`

Comment: That works fine thanks, but is is there a way that the lines are moved up? So far when I replace it with nothing Textpad keeps the empty line.

Comment: In that case, you'll want to match the trailing `\r\n` as well. Just add `(\r\n)?` to the end of the regex (made optional since the newline may be missing on the last line of the file).

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
^(.*[#].*)$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/3neYWN3gTCliDSc_)

or maybe

```
(?<=[\r\n^])(.*[#].*)(?=[\r\n$])
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/236UYSxrPUr57I8U)

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:  Changed to reflect the point by Tim

This

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^.*\\s+#\\s+.*$",Pattern.MULTILINE);

    String[] values = {
        "",
        "###",
        "a#",
        "#a",
        "ab",
        "a#b",
        "a # b\r\na b c"
    };
    for(String input: values){
        Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
        while(m.find()){
            System.out.println(input.substring(m.start(),m.end()));
        }

    }
}
```

gives the output

```
a # b
```

Comment: This is essentially what my regex is doing, but with one problem: `\s` also matches a newline character, so the two lines `a #\nbc` would be matched/removed as well.